# "Falsy or empty" in JavaScript: How to treat {} and [] as false

Tags: javascript

`[]` and `{}` are truthy in javascript.

But I want to treat them as false, and I would love to know how to do it in the least number of characters possible: without external libraries or separate functions, and small enough to fit comfortably between the parentheses of a conditional.

In other words:

> What is the most concise way possible to check an unknown variable (that could be of any type) and return `false` if **either** of these apply: a) it's already falsy; or b) it's `{}` or `[]`?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It's not easy, as T.J. Crowder's answer shows, but more to the point, it shouldn't usually be *necessary*. Why are you in a situation where you don't know whether you're dealing with an array, an object, or something else, and yet need to figure out whether it's falsey by these criteria?

Comment: If it doesn't return false, what should it return?

Answer (score 4):

The most concise way with an array is `!arr.length`. Of course, that assumes you haven't added any non-index properties to the array (which is a perfectly valid thing to do). And as [Qantas 94 Heavy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2074608/qantas-94-heavy) points out in the comments, an array that's empty can have its `length` set to a non-zero value without gaining any actual entries.

Objects are more tricky. What's an "empty" object? One with no properties *at all*? One with no *enumerable* properties? What about properties from its prototype, if any?

If no enumerable properties does it for you, in ES5 you can use `!Object.keys(obj).length`. If you can't count on ES5, you have to have a loop:

```
var empty = true;
var key;
for (key in obj) {
    // Add an `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` check here if you want to filter out prototype properties
    empty = false;
    break;
}
```

...which is obviously fairly ungainly.

You've said you don't want separate functions, but of course that's the best way to do this:

```
var isFalsey = (function() {
    var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

    function isFalsey(x) {
        var key;

        if (!x) {
            return true;
        }
        if (typeof x === "object") {
            if (toString.call(x) === "[object Array]") {
                return !x.length; // Assumes no non-element properties in the array
            }
            for (key in x) {
                // Add an `x.hasOwnProperty(key)` check here if you want to filter out prototype properties
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    return isFalsey;
})();
```

[Example with tests](http://jsbin.com/UMixEKe/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/UMixEKe/1/edit))

Comment: Edge case, I know, but what about if you someone does `arr.length = 1`?

Comment: The OP also said that the check should work for an unknown variable of *any type*. If I have `var a = true;` and then I do `if (!a.length) { console.log('Hello!'); }`, then "Hello!" will certainly be printed.

Comment: @user1436026: I said **for arrays**, `!x.length`. I didn't say for *anything*. `!x.length` also won't work for a non-array object.

Comment: You can use `filter` for arrays: `!!x.filter(function(){return true;}).length`. `filter` will automatically exclude undefined properties set by `arr.length = 1` (sparse arrays).

Answer (score 4):

Given you have variable `x` to check:

```
!(!x || x.length === 0 || JSON.stringify(x) === '{}')
```

Here we go from the back, lets check if `x` is empty:

1. it may be already falsy: `!x`
2. it is Array and its length is zero: `x.length === 0`
3. it is exactly `{}` object: `JSON.stringify(x) === '{}'`

Be careful with `JSON.stringify` method. It is available for majority of modern browsers, but not for IE6,7 if you need to support them. You should check at [caniuse/JSON](http://caniuse.com/json).

Any of this conditions being true will result in variable `x` to be empty.

So we need or's (`||`) and outer `!` to invert result to check if `x` is not empty.

**EDIT:**

More concise way to do 3rd check would be due to @David remark (`JSON.stringify` will not work with object containing methods like `{a: function(){ console.log("test"); }}`):

```
(function (x){ for (key in x) { return 0; } return 1; })(x)
```

So resulting expression is:

```
!(!x || x.length === 0 || (function (x){ for (key in x) { return 0; } return 1; })(x))
```

**EDIT:**

If you wanna support only modern browser, than just use ecmascript 5 feature:

```
// Given x is defined
!(!x || typeof x === 'object' && !Object.keys(x).length)
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify({a:function(){}})` === '{}'`

Comment: @David, thank you for your remark. Maybe do something like `(function (x){ for (key in x) { return false; } return true; })(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the value is either an instance of `Array` or any other primitive (and not a general object,) than you can just put a `+` sign before the object and compare check if it's falsy, like so:

```
> +[] == false
true
> +[1,2] == false
false
> +[] == false
true
> +true == false
false
> +'hello' == false
false
> +25 == false
false
> +false == false
true
```

Dealing with a general instance of object is more complicated as you can see:

```
> +{} == false
false
> +{'a': 'b'} == false
false
```

Or if you know that the value in question is *definitely* not a primitive, and you are using ES 5, then you can use `Object.keys` to get all the keys of the object as an array and then the check becomes like this:

```
> +empty_obj == false || Object.keys(empty_obj) == false
true
> +obj == false || Object.keys(obj) == false
false
```

But if it is a primitive, you are in trouble:

```
> +true == false || Object.keys(true) == false
TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
    at Function.keys (native)
    at repl:1:27
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
```

All in all, you can play around with the `||`, `&&` and `==` operators to try to find something short that will work in all cases all day, but I'm not sure that it's possible.

So, in summary, I would recommend just using a function like the one defined in @T.J. Crowder's  answer.