# How to efficiently detect the existence of any keys of an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, properties, key

What's the fastest way of **detecting the existence** of one or more keys inside an object? Is it possible to do it without iterating over the object by using `Object.keys().length`?
<sub>*This question is almost identical to [How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip)*</sub>

Comment: Are you talking about own properties? Inherited properties? Only enumerable properties?

Comment: Yes, you said it yourself...read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip

Comment: @cookiemonster I'm primarily want to know if the object has any properties in general.

Comment: Very closely related: [“Falsy or empty” in JavaScript: How to treat {} and \[\] as false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476236/falsy-or-empty-in-javascript-how-to-treat-and-as-false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps use this:

```
function hasProperties (obj) {
    for(var x in obj) 
        return true; 
    return false;
}
```

Yes, admittedly you do have to iterate over the object, but you stop after the first property is found.

Comment: This is almost exactly how [jQuery does it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/7e8a91c205723f11cd00c8834f348a649ab15926/src/core.js#L246) for its `isEmptyObject()` function

Comment: Note if you want it to act the same as `Object.keys`, you'll have to include a `hasOwnProperty` check.